# NetLogo: is it possible to access variables of not yet created turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I am writing a piece of code in which investment simulations for different types of factories are run. To calculate if an investment is worth the try, the to-be-build factory (say, steel-factory) is analyzed for revenues and costs in the future. To do that, the turtle (e.g. a company) calculating the investment needs to know the production capacity of the steel-factory.

```
to test
  let future-steel-production ([max-processing-capacity * operational-time] of one-of steel-factories
end
```

But if no steel-factory is build yet (i.e. created), I get the error code:

*OF expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead.*

Is there any way to access an agent's variable, when the agent hasn't been created yet?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to access an agent's variable, when the agent hasn't been created yet?

No. That's a logical impossibility.

But that doesn't mean that you can't figure out the future values of these variables.

You need to ask yourself how you would initialize these variables if you were to actually create the agent. These values (`max-processing-capacity` and `operational-time`) have to come from somewhere, right? Do you some have some definition of factory types stored in a file? Accessed via a reporter or some global variable?

If you were to create a factory with something like:

```
create-factories 1 [
  set max-processing-capacity ???
  set operational-time ???
]
```

...what would you replace `???` with? That's your answer. You need to use whatever you would use at factory creation time when calculating future steel production.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed, I have the values for those factories, but they still need to be accessible before a steel factory has been created in order to decide the steel factory to be created. So I could either create extra variables with the same values to be used, or create a factory at the beginning that is not active in the model, but just provides the values.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but in a similar situation I actually create the agent (in my case a new market), see if it is profitable, and then simply have it die it if it is not.  If the creation involves links to other agents you need to be sure to clean them up before the new agent dies, but presumably you have code to do that when a firm dies naturally.